# Background graphic fine on Desktops but distorted on Phones/Tablets

Tags: html, css, background

I have been trying to figure the issue out for the past few hours but I am not getting anywhere and would be grateful if any experienced people could point me in the right direction.

The background graphic I have put on the website is fine when looked at through a desktop.

URL: http://test.paigroup.com

When you go on the website on a smaller device then the background doesn't sit right and for some reason the whole page is not aligned correctly on the Contact page.

http://test.paigroup.com/contact

The CSS I've used for the background is:

```
body{
    background: url(../img/site/main-bg1.jpg) no-repeat center 130px;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}

body.microsite{
    background: url(../img/site/main-bg1.jpg) no-repeat top;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your **body** tag in css this two line :

```
body{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

And don't forget to use

```
@media
```

Comment: Hi, I've just tried this and it messes up some of the content on other pages and it still doesn't make any difference to the background. :/

Comment: Ok , try to add `width:100%;` but sir i don't see any trouble in your web site can you provide a **Screen Shoot** for your problem.

Comment: i've tried adding that previously with no luck.

It seems ok now I've used "background-size: cover;" but I am still having alignment issues on the Contact page and I don't understand why..

I've added a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: Sorry it won't let me attach a picture view here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hagL.png

Comment: There is a lot of problem in your web page like the search bar in your home page , i notice that the main page and all the other's page are not have he same structure so try to restructuring your page's hope this can help you.